# How to install Xdebug on Mac 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, php, xdebug

I am getting errors when trying to do this. What is the correct way to install Xdebug. From Pear? Pecl?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a user of xDebug, but a [related post](https://superuser.com/questions/37151/install-multiple-php-environments-on-os-x-snow-leopard) on superuser.com refers to [an article](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/maintaining-two-versions-of-php-with-macports) where the guy got the [xDebug binaries](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Downloads/Komodo/RemoteDebugging) from ActiveState. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I did this a while [back](http://chealion.ca/2009/11/xdebug-leopard-and-64-bit-shenanigans/) and the trick was to make sure that Xdebug was compiled as a 64-bit extension by using the command `CFLAGS='-arch x86_64'` before I compiled it from the source (as per the [documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/install)).